# What are the differences between #include<stdio.h> and #include"stdio.h" in C language?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In C language, #include<stdio.h> and #include"stdio.h" are both preprocessor directives used to include the header file such as 'stdio.h' in a C program.

Hope for a better explain about differences between these two methods?